# API Testing - RestAssured - Looping

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I'm doing an assignment for school :

Requirement :

- Create a search ("s) for the items containing "**Fantabulous**"
- Verify that the movie with id "**tt7713068**" is in the list
- Use a json path to generate a list of movie ID's and loop over it to
  search for the movie with the correct ID.

This is what I have:

```
//@Test
public void search_for_movies_on_string_and_validate_one_of_the_results() {
    Response response = given().
            param("apikey", apiKey).
            param("s", "Fantabulous").
        when().get(baseURI).
            then().extract().response();

        JsonPath jsonPath = response.jsonPath();

        List<String> idList = jsonPath.getList("Search.imdbID");
        Assert.assertTrue(idList.contains("tt7713068"));
}
```

How can I loop over a list to search for the movie with the correct ID?

**apiKey** = "7548cb76"

**baseURI** = "http://www.omdbapi.com/"

Answer (score 1):

- Count the size of the list that is returned
- Loop over starting with 0 until the end of the size
- Search for all ID's across the response
  that match your requirement "tt7713068", If it does then print the
  output

  ```
  RestAssured.baseURI = "http://www.omdbapi.com";
  Response response = given().param("apikey", "7548cb76").param("s", "Fantabulous").when().get(baseURI).then().extract().response();

  JsonPath jsonPath = response.jsonPath();

  int count = jsonPath.getInt("Search.size()");

  String id = "tt1634278";

  for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
  {
      String search = jsonPath.getString("Search["+i+"].imdbID");
      if(search.equalsIgnoreCase(id))
      {
          String output = jsonPath.getString("Search["+i+"].Title");
          System.out.println("The ID "+id+" is present in the list and the name of the movie is "+output+"");
      }
  }
  ```

**Output :**

> The ID tt7713068 is present in the list and the name of the movie is
>   Birds of Prey: And the Fantabulous Emancipation of One Harley Quinn